# Aws Lambda Firestore request timed out

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, aws-lambda

I'm trying to use Firestore with aws lambda. (admin-sdk imported via an aws layer).

This code works and returns: "done":"[DEFAULT]"

```
const admin = require('firebase-admin');
const serviceAccount = require('serviceAccount.json');


 exports.lambdaHandler = async (event) => {
     
    try {
    const defaultApp =  admin.initializeApp({
     credential: admin.credential.cert(serviceAccount),
    });


      return {
        statusCode: 200,
        body: JSON.stringify({ done: defaultApp.name}),
      };
    } catch (err) {
      console.error(err);
      return {
        statusCode: 400,
        body: JSON.stringify({ error: `error ${err}`}),
      };
    }
  };
```

But then I add a simple Firestore request.

```
 let db = admin.firestore();
    var docRef = db.collection('test').doc('test');
    await docRef.set({
     first: 'test',
    });
```

And Lambda gives a "timed out" error. "Task timed out after 5.01 seconds".

I'm assuming this function can run within 5 seconds.
Also that the Firebase admin sdk is correctly installed, because I don't get an error when initializing the admin sdk.

The doc doesn't appear in Firestore so my closest guess is that there is something wrong with the code I'm adding.

What am I doing wrong?

Thanks.

Comment: Is your lambda in a VPC / does it have internet access?

Comment: Haven't configured VPC or internet access. Should I? because requests to the url of my neo4j server work.

Comment: If it is not in a VPC you should be okay.

Comment: Just checked, function not connected to a vpc

Comment: I'm seeing a similar issue, where doc.get() is timing out randomly. Did you ever figure anything out @KarelDebedts ?